# Uploading file to drupal 7 from backdoor (FTP) and telling drupal

Tags: php, database, file, upload, drupal-7

I got over 1000 pdf files needed to abe added to drupal contents.
We have drupal content type (page with node) that has upload field.

The files are uploaded into located /var/www/mysite/sites/default/files/ folder

I uploaded one file and search all tables and found **cache_field** has a reference to the file name in a **data** field as BLOB. I downloaded the .bin file from the field and opened it in NotePad++ and found the exact file name with tones of other information.

**My Questions:**
If I know the node ID for each page, is it possible to write php script to update the "contents" page and cache_field table so the files are available for on the page as if they have been uploaded?

Comment: I just found from Ajax error that the files names are stored in the "file_managed" table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the feeds module when you need to update or create a thousand of nodes, with a file associated. 
This module save days of work.

You have just to make a csv file (or any else format the module can read) with the name of each file for each nid.

If you put your pdf files into default/files/folder, you must be sure that your file field locate your file in the folder "folder" before updating with feeds.